# specify lob size in jpa entity

Tags: jpa, blob

I am using openjpa (Websphere Application Server 7) to interact with the database. Is it possible to specify a blob size in the java entity file? It looks like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Lob
@Nullable
private byte[] content;
```

DB2 by defaults gives it a size of 1MB. I want to change that to 20MB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `@Column` annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Lob
@Nullable
@Column(length = 20971520)
private byte[] content;
```

Comment: I found when I set '@Lob
    @Column(length = 52428800)', the database still CLOB(2147483647)

Comment: is the length in bytes or kb?

Comment: The length is in bytes.

Comment: @liamxu 2 147 483 647 bytes is the maximum size for db2 blobs. Look at the IBM documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_lobsintro.html

Comment: about @Column(length=...) apidocs say "Applies only if a string-valued column is used" - https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Column.html#length--